# Cannot display text while process is running c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I have an application which programs firmware to an ST-LINK using ST-LINK_CLI.exe.

The user chooses a firmware, presses start and the process begins. However it takes quite a while for the board to program and the user may think that the program has crashed. I want a text block to display 'Board Programming..." so that they know it is working.

However, at the moment the code doesn't display the text until it has already been programmed and I'm not sure why. The following is my code on the click start button event:

```
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(); //new process start info
        start.FileName = STPath; //set file name
        start.Arguments = "-C -ME -p " + firmwareLocation + " -v -Run"; //set arguments
        start.UseShellExecute = false; //set shell execute (need this to redirect output)
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect output
        start.RedirectStandardInput = true; //redirect input
        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //hide window
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; //create no window


        using (Process process = Process.Start(start)) //create process
        {

            try
            {

                while (process.HasExited == false) //while open
                {
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(); //send enter key
                    programmingTextBlock.Text = "Board Programming...";
                }

                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) //create stream reader
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd(); //read till end of process
                    File.WriteAllText("File.txt", result); //write to file
                }

            }
            catch { } //so doesn't blow up
            finally
            {
                int code = process.ExitCode; //get exit code
                codee = code.ToString(); //set code to string
                File.WriteAllText("Code.txt", codee); //save code
              }
```

Is there anyway to get the text to display before the process begins to run or whilst the process is running?

Thanks
Lucy

Comment: To manipulate UI and do something else at the time You need to use another thred.

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that while the `while` loop is running, as it is in the main thread, the UI is not going to refresh. The right way of solving this is putting the "problematic" code in another thread, using a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) or a [Background Worker](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/).

Alternately, you could take this `programmingTextBlock.Text = "Board Programming...";` outside the `while` loop and then add this line:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                      new Action(delegate { }));
```

This should "refresh" the ui before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about `Waiting Bar` that should appear during long execution process and dissappear when it done. Aren't you?
To do that you should implement `async/await` pattern to prevent UI thread stucking.
In your view model:

```
            this.IsBusy = true;
            await MyTaskMethodAsync();
            this.IsBusy = false;
```

Whereas `MyTaskMethodAsync` returns `Task`.
In your `XAML` define your `Busy Bar` and binding to `IsBusy` property you can see in `C#` code:

```
 <Border Visibility="{Binding IsBusy,Converter={converters:BooleanToSomethingConverter TrueValue='Visible', FalseValue='Collapsed'}}"
            Background="#50000000"
            Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Loading. . ."
                   FontSize="16" />
    </Border>
```